# In Ubuntu use GTK file save dialog from bash command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, gtk

I would like to do something like

```
gtk-file-saver /tmp/tempfile.txt
```

And then a GTK file saver pops up for the user. By this I mean the normal dialog that is used whenever you do "Save As" in most GUI apps on Ubuntu.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: check out this http://askubuntu.com/questions/488350/how-to-prompt-users-with-a-gui-dialog-box-to-choose-file-directory-path-via-the